# Formal name and software implementation of a graph theory problem

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I have a bipartite graph SKUs $\times$ customers. Two vertices are connected if a customer bought that SKU (at least $k$ times). I want to find $n$ SKUs that cover as many customers as possible.

Does this problem have a formal name? Do you know any software for solving it?

Comment: This problem is similar to ["Hitting set problem"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116514/is-there-a-name-for-this-bipartite-graph-problem).